# Scala immutable variables and printing

Tags: scala, printing, immutability

Currently taking a class that's using Scala which I've never used before, so the syntax and itself is new.

I'm working on a simple division function but am running into some errors.

First of all, am I using var sub=m right? In my code I simply wanted to do m = m-n but you can't change the variable, and I'm not sure what the best alternative is.
Then my only other problem is the compiler barks at me for my print line..

```
<console>:14: error: reassignment to val
        m = m-n
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Int
        println(x)
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
def div(m: Int, n: Int): Int = {
    var x = 0
    var sub = m
    if (n > m)
        print("Can't perform that.")

    while (sub >= n) {
        x+=1
        sub = sub-n
    }
println(x)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is actually your return value. You declared `div` to return an `Int` and the compiler (in your case) is assuming your last statement to be your return value. Since `println` returns `Unit` (it's a `void` function), the compiler is confused.

You can explicitly return a value by saying `return x` anywhere in your function, or you can put `x` as the last statement in the function (or one particular path of execution in that function). For example:

```
def what(b:Boolean):Int = {
  if(b) 1
  else 0
}
```

(Scala would allow me to write `def what(b:Boolean) = if(b) 1 else 0` and it would be exactly the same function as above, but that is besides the point.)

For convenience, here is your function with the modification I described:

```
def div(m: Int, n: Int): Int = {
  var x = 0
  var sub = m
  if (n > m)
    print("Can't perform that.")

  while (sub >= n) {
    x+=1
    sub = sub-n
  }
  println(x)
  x // <--- return value
}
```

Comment: Does it always take the last statement as the return?
Also, am I using the var sub = m method right? It just seems like thats adding unnecessary crap, but you obviously can't just do m = m-n

Comment: @johnredyns Yes, sub = m is right, in Scala the argument of function/method is always a val, you could not do reassignment on them. And in most case, Scala use functional approach (ex. recursive) to solve kind of problem you describe, so IMHO it's not a big deal that arguments could not be reassignment.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, putting more idiomatic recursive definition here:

```
def div(m: Int, n: Int): Int = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(count: Int, sub: Int): Int = 
    if (sub < n) count
    else loop(count + 1, sub - n)

  loop(0, m)
}
```