# Why type mismatch error?

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scala immutable variables and printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395682/scala-immutable-variables-and-printing)

I am confused why this will not run as i expect it to, I have tried to change it multiple times and it still give an error stating that it is given `Unit` and needs `Int`.

```
def div(m: Int, n: Int): Int = {
  var counter = 0
  var p = m 
  while (p >= 0) {
    p -= n
    counter += 1
    println(counter)
  }
}
```

Comment: I just answered this same question yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395682/scala-immutable-variables-and-printing

Answer (score 10):

In scala result of last operation would be return value. In your piece of code last operation is `while` loop that doesn't return anything (or, if you want, return `Unit` which is the same as nothing) while you specified return value of `Int`.

So if you need to return value of p write this:

```
def div(m: Int, n: Int): Int = {
  var counter = 0
  var p = m 
  while (p >= 0) {
    p -= n
    counter += 1
    println(counter)
  }
  p
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Scala function returns result of the last expression. Last expression of your "div"-function is the while-loop, which returns no value, so the type of result in your function is Unit ("void" in Java)